# Forest package - Drop nodes to lowest possible layer

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams, forest, trees

I have the following `forest` code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[linguistics]{forest}

\begin{document}

\begin{forest}
    for tree={
        if n children=0{
            font=\scshape,
            tier=terminal,
        }{},
    }
[Ġentertainment
    [Ġen
        [Ġ]
        [en
            [e]
            [n]
        ]
    ]
    [tertainment
        [tert
            [ter
                [t]
                [er
                    [e]
                    [r]
                ]
            ]
            [t]
        ]
        [ainment
            [ain
                [a]
                [in
                    [i]
                    [n]
                ]
            ]
            [ment
                [m]
                [ent
                    [en
                        [e]
                        [n]
                    ]
                    [t]
                ]
            ]
        ]
    ]
]
\end{forest}
\end{document}
```

It results in the following tree:

[image: forest diagram]

It's clear that this has some very long lines, which isn't strictly necessary: for example, note that there is one node "en" on the upper left, but also one on the lower right. The one on the left is clearly too high up (which is caused by its smaller distance to the root). Here's an example I drew for where I want the "en" node to be:

[image: forest diagram]

I want to do this **automatically** and **for all nodes** (so also "er" and "in"), **while keeping the leaves aligned**. Is this possible?

Comment: You can have more than one `tier`. You can use assign a tier to all the nodes that should appear on the same level. (Though, a more automatic approach would be nice.)

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel Preferably there is a single configuration I can enable or disable in the "forest preamble", because although I am exporting these trees from Python, I don't want to regenerate all the `forest` code when I want to switch from one style to another.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code below automatically assigns tier names based on the "reverse level" of a node. The leaves are assigned to tier `0`, their parents to tier `1`, etc.

We walk the tree with `for tree children-first`, which processes the children before their parents.  The aggregate function `.max` is an easy way to compute the `tier` of a branching node: it walks the `children` of a node, and computes the maximum of their `tier`s, plus one; because it is used as a pfgkeys handler of `tier` (`tier/.max`), the result it assigned to the parent `tier˙.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[linguistics]{forest}

\begin{document}

\begin{forest}
    for tree={
        if n children=0{
            font=\scshape,
        }{},
    },
    for tree children-first={
      if n children=0{
        tier=0,
      }{
        tier/.max={1+tier}{children},
      },
    },
[Ġentertainment
    [Ġen
        [Ġ]
        [en
            [e]
            [n]
        ]
    ]
    [tertainment
        [tert
            [ter
                [t]
                [er
                    [e]
                    [r]
                ]
            ]
            [t]
        ]
        [ainment
            [ain
                [a]
                [in
                    [i]
                    [n]
                ]
            ]
            [ment
                [m]
                [ent
                    [en
                        [e]
                        [n]
                    ]
                    [t]
                ]
            ]
        ]
    ]
]
\end{forest}
\end{document}
```

[image: resulting tree]

Comment: Would it be more efficient to combine the two `if n children=0` bits? Intuitively, it seems as if the first time the code walks the tree is unnecessary and it would be quicker to just walk the tree the second time, but I find it hard to keep track of what's quicker and what's not.

Comment: I would say you're right!